# One point compactifition

Tags: general-topology, alexandroff-compactification

I have one little problem with one point compactification. Here is example:
Let $Z = \alpha \mathbb N = \mathbb N \cup \{\alpha\}$ one point compactification discrete spaces $\mathbb N$ of natural number.

I know that open sets are shapes $\{\alpha\} \cup \mathbb N \backslash K$, where $K$ is compact subset of $\mathbb N$. $\mathbb N$ is discrete space so only finite subsets of $\mathbb N$ are compact.

Question: How to prove that $Z$ is compact?

Comment: Welcome. “How to show the one-point (Alexandroff) compactification is compact?” Has been asked before (by me, for instance!) and can be found in probably many different places with a Google search. I’ll bring up the post for you

Comment: Does [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4393170/815585) answer your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to show that every open cover of the one-point compactification of $\mathbb{N}$ has a finite subcover. The open subsets of the one-point compactification are typically taken to be any open set of the original space (in this case $\mathbb{N}$), or the compactification minus a compact set of the original space (in this case $(\{\alpha\} \cup \mathbb{N}) \setminus C$, where $C$ is a finite set of $\mathbb{N}$).

Let $\mathcal{U}$ be an open cover of $\{\alpha\} \cup \mathbb{N}$. Then there must be some $U_1 \in \mathcal{U}$ such that $\alpha \in U_1$, and looking at the open sets described above, we see that this $U_1$ must exclude only finitely many points of $\{\alpha\} \cup \mathbb{N}$. Can you finish from there?

Comment: So $U_{1}$ can be $(\{\alpha\} \cup \mathbb N) \backslash C_{1}$, where $C_{1}$ is compact subset of $\mathb N$. I am not sure I can finish. I will try.